# It doesn't sleep as expected

Tags: c++, sleep

Considering that this prints something like

```
[E] [F] [A] [C] [A] 
[B] [F] [B] [B] [D] 
[C] [C] [C] [C] [C]
```

The following wait 5 seconds and print a row instead of executing each `[...]` and wait 1 second, why?

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
            int a = randomInt(0, 5);
            sleep(1);
            cout << "[" << allowed[a] << "] ";
            usciti[i][j] = allowed[a];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: I suspect you just need to flush() the buffer at the right point...

Comment: I'm unable to replicated this. It works fine for me.

Comment: @razlebe that could be it, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @razlebe You bet me to it. Jeff, you should mark his as the answer if he posts it please.

Comment: @Luchian, Dennis - thanks. Posted as comment as I was literally passing by and didn't have time to pen a proper answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably because you are not flushing the std::cout stream until the `endl` (which flushes as well). You could use a call to `cout.flush()` to do that.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 4; ++j) {
        int a = randomInt(0, 5);
        sleep(1);
        cout << "[" << allowed[a] << "] " << std::flush;
        usciti[i][j] = allowed[a];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Like this you `flush` the `cout`. `cout << endl;` will then just start a new line.

In your code you are writing to the buffer, until flushing it with `endl` (plus adding a new line). For details see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/flush/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe output is buffered? Look at this function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/flush/